# Pubnub.history() paging

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I'm trying to implement paging for `pubnub.history()`.  Here is what I have so far:

**Attempt 1:**  This gets the *first* `count` messages from the beginning of time:

```
function getHistory(chnl,count, token) {
    var pagesize=10;
    console.log('Starting at ' + token + ', getting ' + count);
    pubnub.history({
        channel : chnl,
        callback : function(m){
            var msgs = m[0];
            var msgcount = msgs.length;
            var startToken = m[1];
            var endToken = m[2];
            for (var i = 0; i < msgcount; i++) {
                var msg = msgs[i];
                processMessage(chnl,msg);
            }
            if (count >= pagesize) {
                getHistory(chnl,count - pagesize,endToken);
            }
        },
        count: pagesize,
        start: token,
        reverse: true
    });
}
```

**Attempt 2:**  This gets the most recent `pagesize` messages over and over again.  `token` is the same every time:

```
function getHistory(chnl,count, token) {
    var pagesize=10;
    console.log('Starting at ' + token + ', getting ' + count);
    pubnub.history({
        channel : chnl,
        callback : function(m){
            var msgs = m[0];
            var msgcount = msgs.length;
            var startToken = m[1];
            var endToken = m[2];
            for (var i = 0; i < msgcount; i++) {
                var msg = msgs[i];
                processMessage(chnl,msg);
            }
            if (count >= pagesize) {
                getHistory(chnl,count - pagesize,startToken);
            }
        },
        count: pagesize,
        end: token,
        reverse: false
    });
}
```

I need to get the last `count` messages, *ending with the most recent*.  How can I modify my function to do this?

---

**UPDATE: My new API v4 code:**

```
function getHistory(chnl,count, token) {
    var pagesize=10;
    console.log('Starting at ' + token + ', getting ' + count);
    pubnub.history({
        channel : chnl,
        callback : function(m){

        },
        count: pagesize,
        start: token,
        reverse: true
    },function(status, response) {
        var msgs = response.messages;
        var msgcount = msgs.length;
        var startToken = response.startTimeToken;
        var endToken = response.endTimeToken;
        for (var i = 0; i < msgcount; i++) {
            var msg = msgs[i];
            processMessage(msg);
        }
        if (count >= pagesize) {
            getHistory(chnl,count - pagesize,endToken);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is what it is doing right now if I request 1000:

> ```
> 2016-10-25 13:29:59.060 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772721032416580, getting 620
> 2016-10-25 13:29:59.385 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772748031396800, getting 610
> 2016-10-25 13:29:59.678 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772778027380036, getting 600
> 2016-10-25 13:30:00.024 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772808029462014, getting 590
> 2016-10-25 13:30:00.440 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772838027743668, getting 580
> 2016-10-25 13:30:00.772 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772868026780088, getting 570
> 2016-10-25 13:30:01.116 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772898023567196, getting 560
> 2016-10-25 13:30:01.426 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772928025649280, getting 550
> 2016-10-25 13:30:01.726 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14772958026355252, getting 540
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.113 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14773220007794584, getting 530
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.457 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 520
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.606 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 510
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.690 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 500
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.790 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 490
> 2016-10-25 13:30:02.922 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 480
> 2016-10-25 13:30:03.015 pubnub.js:23 Starting at 14774200653664656, getting 470
> ```

As you can see in this instance, there weren't actually 1000 messages so at `13:30:02.467` it started getting the same message over and over. I then requested 300 and it worked, but it got the *first* 300, not the most recent 300.

So two issues still remain:

1. Get all messages if requested number is more than exist.
2. Get *most recent* x messages.

Comment: If you only ever want < 100 than you do not need to page through history. So if you always want messages since a point in time and newer, than you should always use the default/max count (pagesize) of 100. That said, you will then need to always to change the `token` value. If it stays the same it will always give you the same set of results. And if you use the `end` parameter, then you will get the duplicate message when get the next set of results (assuming you are changing the value of `token`). Working on code for you.

Comment: To clarify, I definitely want more than 100 results.  That was the whole point in implementing paging :)  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Cool, it was just that the pagesize = 10 gives the impression you need < 100, so paging wouldn't be necessary. And I see that you are changing the value of `token` using the `startToken`. My eyes missed that on first pass.

Comment: Yeah, I added the `pagesize` variable for troubleshooting and to try to smooth out the loading of the results (the smaller page size makes the history load more smoothly)

Comment: Do you insist on PubNub JavaScript SDK v3 or can I provide SDK v4 sample code?

Comment: Hmm, v4 looks pretty different.  But if it's a lot easier to solve this problem then that is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126651/discussion-between-craig-conover-and-scott).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Storage - Paging with History

### Some setup

- I have put together a recursive paging function and a set of steps to test it. Keep in mind this code is as simple as possible while still being somewhat functional for a POC, but it is not best practices.
- And this is PubNub JavaScript SDK v4, instead of v3 for which the question was originally asked.

**First, initialize an instance of PubNub using your own keys**

```js
// init PubNub
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey   : 'pub-...',
    subscribeKey : 'sub-...'
})
```

**Second, create a function to populate a channel**

We want to create a channel with messages that we can easily understand the order of those message: *message #1*, message #2, etc.

We use setInterval to add some delay between the published messages. First, we want to be sure that the messages are stored in the order we publish (remember, it's all async, including on the server side) and we want some *time spacing* between our message timetokens.

```js
function pub(channel, total) {
    var i = 1;

    var looper = setInterval(
        function() {
            pubnub.publish({
                channel: channel,
                message: "message #" + i++
            });

            if (i > total) {
                clearInterval(looper);
            }
        }, 
    400);
}
```

You can create a several different test channels with different number of messages but one with 32 message ought to do the trick for simple history paging testing. You want a *non-round* number so you can page by 5 or 10 and see what the uneven end results gives you. It is useful to have another channel with *round number* to see that as well.

**Finally, create the history paging function**

It's a bit crude but it gets the job done without too much fanciness to get in the way of pointing out what is happening. It uses recursion and not optimally.

```js
function getMessages(args, callback) {
    pubnub.history(
        {
            // search starting from this timetoken
            start: args.startToken,
            channel: args.channel,
            // false - search forwards through the timeline
            // true - search backwards through the timeline
            reverse: args.reverse,
            // limit number of messages per request to this value; default/max=100
            count: args.pagesize,
            // include each returned message's publish timetoken
            includeTimetoken: true,
            // prevents JS from truncating 17 digit timetokens
            stringifiedTimeToken: true
        },
        function(status, response) {
            // holds the accumulation of resulting messages across all iterations
            var results = args.results;
            // the retrieved messages from history for this iteration only
            var msgs = response.messages;
            // timetoken of the first message in response
            var firstTT = response.startTimeToken;
            // timetoken of the last message in response
            var lastTT = response.endTimeToken;
            // if no max results specified, default to 500
            args.max = !args.max ? 500 : args.max;

            if (msgs != undefined && msgs.length > 0) {
                // display each of the returned messages in browser console
                for (var i in msgs) {
                    msg = msgs[i];
                    console.log(msg.entry, msg.timetoken);
                }

                // first iteration, results is undefined, so initialize with first history results
                if (!results) results = msgs;
                // subsequent iterations, results has previous iterartions' results, so concat
                // but concat to end of results if reverse true, otherwise prepend to begining of results
                else args.reverse ? results = results.concat(msgs) : results = msgs.concat(results);
            }

            // show the total messages returned out of the max requested
            console.log('total    : ' + results.length + '/' + args.max);

            // we keep asking for more messages if # messages returned by last request is the
            // same at the pagesize AND we still have reached the total number of messages requested
            // same as the opposit of !(msgs.length < pagesize || total == max)
            if (msgs.length == args.pagesize && results.length < args.max) {
                getMessages(
                    {
                        channel:args.channel, max:args.max, reverse:args.reverse, 
                        pagesize:args.pagesize, startToken:args.reverse ? lastTT : firstTT, results:results
                    }, 
                    callback);
            }
            // we've reached the end of possible messages to retrieve or hit the 'max' we asked for
            // so invoke the callback to the original caller of getMessages providing the total message results
            else callback(results);
        }
    );
}
```

### Test the Paging

We will assume that we have a channel named `test1` with 32 messages in Storage as follows:

- message #1
- message #2

...

- message #32

each with a unique timetoken.

Invoke the `getMessages` function to get the following desired results:

**1. get maximum 50 messages starting from the oldest message, 5 messages at a time**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 50, pagesize: 5, reverse: true
    },
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

**2. get maximum of 20 messages starting from the oldest message, 5 messages at a time**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 20, pagesize: 5, reverse: true
    },
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

**3. get maximum of 50 messages starting from the newest message, 5 messages at a time**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 50, pagesize: 5, reverse: false
    },
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

**4. get maximum of 20 messages starting from the newest message, 5 messages at a time**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 20, pagesize: 5, reverse: false
    },
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

So you should see that the **order** of the returned messages of each invocation of `history` is always oldest to newest (ascending). But the order in which the messages are searched depends on the `reverse` parameter.

- `reverse:true` will retrieve blocks of message from the oldest to the newest: 1,2,3,4,5 | 6,7,8,9,10 | ...
- `reverse:false` will retrieve blocks of message from the newest to the oldest: 28,29,30,31,32 | 23,24,25,26,27 | ...

So to reiterate, order of the messages in each response is the same, but the direction of search/retrieve is different. NOTE: this is something the new Storage/History design will clear up with simpler, more robust APIs (for example: `getMessagesSince`, `getMessagesBefore`, `getMessagesBetween`).

Now let's introduce the `startToken` parameter so we can retrieve message from or to a given point in the channel's history timeline. The timetoken you specify will be one that you need to pick from an existing message in the channel's history. It will be different for you than for me since we published at different times with different keys. I will use `startToken:14774567814936359` for the following examples and let's assume this is the timetoken for *message #17*.

**5. get maximum of 20 messages starting from message at timetoken *14774567814936359*, 5 messages at a time (remember that `start` param is *exclusive* so you will not get *message #17* back in your results)**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 20, pagesize: 5, reverse: true,
        startToken:"14774567814936359"
    }, 
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

*NOTE: You have to pass the timetoken values as strings (notice that `startToken` param value is quoted above, and below) otherwise JavaScript will round them up. For example, 147745678149363**59** will become 147745678149363**60** and you will get unexpected results. Go ahead and try it without the quotes and you will see that the message at the provided timetoken will be retrieved, but it should be excluded. You can see the rounded up timetoken in the history URL that was submitted by checking in the Network tab of your browser.*

**6. get maximum of 20 messages prior to the message at timetoken *14774567814936359*, 5 messages at a time**

```js
getMessages(
    {
        channel: 'test1', max: 50, pagesize: 5, reverse: false,
        startToken:"14774567814936359"
    }, 
    function(results) {
        console.log("results: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

We could go on and on with more examples, but I'll let you (Scott) and others ask for how-to examples and I can provide as necessary.

### Ordering history results

The `getMessages` function assembles the resulting array of messages in a presorted ascending order even when messages are retrieve from newest to oldest order. It does this by *prepending* the new history results with the current accumulation of previous iterations' results.

If the desire is to sort messages in descending timetoken order, then it is fairly simple to implement a sort comparator function to do so. I provide a simple example of this here:

```js
function sortHistory(messages, desc, callback) {
    messages.sort(function(a, b) {
        var e1 = desc ? b : a;
        var e2 = desc ? a : b;
        return parseInt(e1.timetoken) - parseInt(e2.timetoken);
    });
    
    callback(messages);
}
```

This `sortHistory` function accepts the messages array (an array of JSON elements: `{message, timetokens}`), a flag that indicates the desired sort order (ascending is default, set to true for descending), and a function that will be called with the resulting sorted array messages.

Now let's call `getMessages` with `revers:true`. This means that the messages will be retrieved in oldest to newest and if we want ascending sort order, then it is already in that order.

```js
getMessages({channel: 'test1', max: 100, pagesize: 5, reverse: true}, 
    function(results) {
        console.log("presorted: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));       
    }
);
```

If we want to sort the messages in descending order, we just add a call to our `sortHistory` function.

```js
getMessages({channel: 'test1', max: 100, pagesize: 5, reverse: true}, 
    function(results) {
        console.log("before sort: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));

        // sort messages in descending order
        sortHistory(results, true, function(sorted) {
            console.log("after sort: \n" + JSON.stringify(sorted));
        });        
    }
);
```

And if we retrieve the message with `reverse:false`, newest to oldest, then we still get the messages assembled in ascending order even though the iterations in chunks of size `pagesize` (16,17,18,19,20 | 11,12,13,14,15...). But if we want to sort descending, again, just need to call the `sortHistory` function.

```js
getMessages({channel: 'test1', max: 100, pagesize: 5, reverse: false}, 
    function(results) {
        console.log("before sort: \n" + JSON.stringify(results));

        // sort messages in descending order
        sortHistory(results, true, function(sorted) {
            console.log("after sort: \n" + JSON.stringify(sorted));
        });        
    }
);
```

> I updated the jsfiddle with new code and I made a lot of mods to this answer.

See the PubNub [JavaScript SDK Storage (history)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) Docs/Tutorial] for full details and the PubNub [Storage and History tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-storage-and-playback).

Comment: Okay I made a fiddle. It subscribes to a channel that has 20 messages.  With reverse set to false it actually does get the most recent 10 messages but they are in the wrong order.  https://jsfiddle.net/dpko62vt/2/

Comment: Changing the page size to 1 works but would be a little inefficient... :)

Comment: This has something to do with async in the display because the PubNub Debug Console outputs them in correct order. Doing to some testing and will be back with more.

Comment: Must be something to do with JSFiddle's display mechanism. Because when I run this local on my machine from browser console, I get the proper order as I do from Debug Console.  

{text: "16"} "14775060510889110"
{text: "17"} "14775060527115734"
{text: "18"} "14775060549966464"
{text: "19"} "14775060598687903"
{text: "20"} "14775060621112021"
total    : 5/10
{text: "11"} "14775060436686941"
{text: "12"} "14775060451661651"
{text: "13"} "14775060467511847"
{text: "14"} "14775060481887591"
{text: "15"} "14775060495761662"
total    : 10/10

Comment: Ah, I see. You are getting them i the right order. It is as I described in my answer. Your getting 16-20, then 11-15. `reverse:false` means search from newest to oldest. So it gets the newest 5 messages, then gets the next 5 before that, and so on. I did say we are working on a much better API so that you don't have to think about how the message are retrieved and how to page through the timeline. Trust me, I know it isn't optimal.

Comment: Let me know if that need further explanation but see my answer just under point #4: *4. get maximum of 20 messages*

Comment: This means I'll have to store them in some sort of array and re-sort them which is, as you implied, fairly inconvenient.  Correct?

Comment: Then search with `reverse:true`, but it's not that much work to sort the array. See added code in my answer above at the end.

Comment: if I set `reverse:true` I get records `1..10`

Comment: New fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/dpko62vt/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126864/discussion-between-scott-and-craig-conover).